# Softalyer API - calling getBlockDeviceTemplateGroups

Tags: php, api, templates, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

we have a problem in using getBlockDeviceTemplateGroups(): It returns always "blockDevicesDiskSpaceTotal" values as zero.

**PHP CODE:**

```
$mask = "mask[name, blockDevicesDiskSpaceTotal, storageRepository[billingItem[associatedBillingItem]], createDate, datacenter, datacenters,id,parentId]";
$client = SoftLayer_SoapClient::getClient('SoftLayer_Account', null, $apiUsername, $apiKey);
$client->setObjectMask($mask);
```

//Retrieve private template group objects (parent and children) and the shared template group objects (parent only) for an account.
$templates = $client->getBlockDeviceTemplateGroups();

**OUTPUT of print_r($templates):**

```
Array
 (
     [0] => stdClass Object
         (
            [createDate] => 2016-02-29T17:42:04+01:00
            [id] => 966271
            [name] => 20160229-JMeter-Master.bluereply.it
            [parentId] =>
            [blockDevicesDiskSpaceTotal] => 0
            [datacenters] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 814994
                            [longName] => Amsterdam 3
                            [name] => ams03
                            [statusId] => 2
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 815394
                            [longName] => Milan 1
                            [name] => mil01
                            [statusId] => 2
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [createDate] => 2016-02-29T17:31:10+01:00
            [id] => 966247
            [name] => 20160229-JMeter-Slave.bluereply.it
            [parentId] =>
            [blockDevicesDiskSpaceTotal] => 0
            [datacenters] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 815394
                            [longName] => Milan 1
                            [name] => mil01
                            [statusId] => 2
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 814994
                            [longName] => Amsterdam 3
                            [name] => ams03
                            [statusId] => 2
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 449500
                            [longName] => Paris 1
                            [name] => par01
                            [statusId] => 2
                        )

                )

    and so on...
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try using this objectMask:

```
mask[name, blockDevicesDiskSpaceTotal, storageRepository[billingItem[associatedBillingItem]],children[blockDevicesDiskSpaceTotal,datacenter], createDate, datacenter, datacenters,id,parentId]
```

the problem is that the images templates have a container which stores the real images templates for each datacenter, currently you are getting the "blockDevicesDiskSpaceTotal" of the container which is empty, you need to get that information form the container's children.

Regards